# Integration swift framework in swift project, both using cocoapods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, cocoa-touch

i have a cocoa touch framework which uses cocoapods and a swift project which uses cocoapods (some libs in the framework are used both internally in the framework and in the project)

How can i integrate the framework in the project, knowing that both use xcworkspace ?

(i would firstly prefer subproject system because i'm still developping the lib…)

---

Situation on 22/07/2015
Here's where i am now :

3rd party libs (like Alamofire) are integrated in my framework with the subproject draag'n'drop system.
Then my framework is integrated in my product project with cocoapods (private pod repo)

Problem : i have a class in my product project which must import the lib Alamofire but it cannot find it.

How can i make the 3rd party libs integrated in my framework accessible in my product project ?

Answer (score 0):

- Import the framework in your project.
- Then, open the Podfile of the frameworks, and copy/paste all of the needed dependencies in the Podfile of your project.
- Finally, use `$ pod install` to install dependencies.

Comment: I don't really know how to import the framework in the project with subfolder technique since with cocoapods, it now uses a xcode workspace…